# Managing nuget versions from beta to release in VS2017 for .net core2.1 when building pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

I need to create nuget package for a .net core 2.1 as part of build and release process in Azure Devops
What I would like to do

1) In the build section build the project and then add the compiled code to artifact

2) In Release definition will have 2 deployments one for Beta release where the version will be like 1.2.3-Beat.2 and push to azure artifact nuget and another deployment to release where the version will be like 1.2.3.2 and push to azure artifact nuget.

Currently I have only one build definition which will build (nuget package gets created during build process) and push to azure artifact nuget.

[image]

Pipeline I would like to create

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dotnet pack` task with the `--no-build` option, and in your pre-release stage set the **VersionSuffix** value.

Note: My current team uses a set of Powershell scripts to append build number data to the Major.Minor data found in the .csproj (or AssemblyInfo.cs for netFramework), but that doesn't change the answer to your question. Once you figure out what the Major.Minor.Patch[.Build] data is going to be, you can use the **VersionSuffix** property in a `dotnet pack` task with `--no-build` to communicate quality of the package as it moves through your pipeline.

[image]

Given a `.csproj` file that looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0.1</PackageVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1812.201</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.1812.201</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assemblies\*">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Again, if we ignore the versioning step that we use, the **dotnet pack** task in the pipeline image above will produce a package with the version `1.0.0.1-Beta`.

Then in your stable release stage, don't set the suffix value and let the package get its version from the .csproj file like normal (eg. `1.0.0.1`).

---

The elements and values in the sample `.csproj` file above can be written as  direct edits to the `.csproj` or they can be set using the **Properties >> Package** tab.

If the values are not changed in the properties menu or added explicitly, the elements and values do not appear in the `.csproj` and are assumed by **dotnet build|test|pack** commands.

[image]

---

Finding the right combination of these properties and values can be daunting if you aren't familiar with how they're fitted together. I found [this article](https://andrewlock.net/version-vs-versionsuffix-vs-packageversion-what-do-they-all-mean/) useful when trying to decipher the version properties.

Also, you should understand `1.0.1-b2` < `1.0.1`, so your pre-release version might be `1.2.3.2-beta1` and your stable version would be `1.2.3.2`.

---

[image: go to nuget doc]

Comment: From the example provided it looks like in the build definition itself you are assigning version to the package for Beta so when and how do I create a package which assign version for final release. I have updated with the pipeline I would like to create. Do I create package with both beta and release version during the Build process

Comment: @kumar My build pipeline image is only showing the assignment of the **Beta** suffix. The other version information (ie. Major.Minor.Patch) is pulled from the .csproj file (for our situation we are packing via the .csproj file not a .nuspec file). I'll add to the example to try and tie this together.

Comment: I tried what you had mentioned but -beta suffix is not getting applied. any thoughts what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you getting some error? Make sure you're not overriding the **[Version](https://andrewlock.net/version-vs-versionsuffix-vs-packageversion-what-do-they-all-mean/#version)** property somewhere, either by setting it in the `.csproj` file or by some other option to a `dotnet` command.

Comment: also if you do not mind where and how you define version format like the above 4.0.1-beta-23516

Comment: There are several ways. Being that your project is .Net Core I suggest using the `.csproj` as in my sample. These 3 values can also be set using the **context-click >> properties >> package tab** for your project. The xml elements aren't visible in the .csproj if you leave the default values in properties, and **dotnet** will assume the value for them. [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops#example-version-your-assemblies) is a sample from MS that can be a base for your build to "update" the files @ build time if you want to.

Comment: note: the script behind the link in the above comment is updating `AssemblyInfo.*` files found in `Properties*` and `My Project` directories. For **.Net Core (2.1)** following my suggestion above, you would change this script to modify the `.csproj` files. This is what we are doing to append **Patch.Build** data from the build number of the CI pipeline that packaged the resource.

Answer (score 1):

As the package version is included the moment you perform 'nuget pack', which you would generally perform during build, it might become a bit complicated to change that version afterwards.

What may be interesting in your case is using the concept of views in Azure Artifacts, this would allow you to promote a package to the release view at a later state without having to rebuild the package.
There is a nice extension on the marketplace that would allow you to do this from within a release: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task

using this flow you can have the packages in the pre-release view/feed as long as you like and make them available in the release view whenever you see fit.

downside of this is that the packages are not identified as pre-release packages by Nuget as you would not be packaging them with the proper semver for that

Comment: You're right @RemcoBrilstra. These packages are identified by the way the feed is accessed. Including `@pre` or `@rel` in the url of the feed when using it as a package source is the only way you know the quality of the package.